# Setting a dynamic variable name that receives an argument in ruby capybara

Tags: ruby, capybara

I am trying to set a variable name based on a value passed by the user

My capybara step looks like this:

```
When(/^I have a value to save for user [0-9]$/) do |number|
  @user_value_#{number} = another_variable
end
```

This doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Object#instance_variable_set, so

```
instance_variable_set(“@user_value_#{number}”, another_variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed this:

```
 When(/^I have a value to save for user [0-9]$/) do |number|
   @user_value ||= {}
   @user_value[number]
 end
```

I hope this helps